# How to call axios on submit button in react-dropzone?

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

How can I call the axios when the user clicks the submit button?

Unable to add an onclick event handler on the submit button, where shall I declare the onClick event function which calls axios or accepts acceptedFiles variable in this code.

useCallback is called when the user drops files, and files get automatically uploaded when the user drops the files. I want files to be uploaded when the user clicks submit button.

```
import React, {useCallback, Component} from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';
import axios from 'axios';


function Basic(props) {

const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    let formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i < acceptedFiles.length; i++) {
        let file = acceptedFiles[i];
        formData.append('articleFiles[]', file);
    }  

    axios({
      method: 'post',

      data: formData,
      )}


}, [])
const {acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({onDrop});


const files = acceptedFiles.map(file => (
    <li key={file.path}>
        {file.path}
        - {file.size}
        bytes
    </li>
));



return (
    <section className="container">
        <div {...getRootProps({className: 'dropzone'})}>
            <input {...getInputProps()}/>
            <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
        </div>
        {files.length > 0 && <React.Fragment>
            <div>
                <h4>Files</h4>
                <ul>{files}</ul>
            </div>
            <button>Submit</button> //<---
        </React.Fragment>}

    </section>
);
}

 export class UploadManuscript extends Component {

render() {


    return (<Basic/>)
}
}

export default UploadManuscript
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done it:

```html
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';
import axios from 'axios'

function Basic(props) {

    const uploadFiles = () => {
        let formData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i < acceptedFiles.length; i++) {
            let file = acceptedFiles[i];
            formData.append('articleFiles[]', file);
        }
       
       
        axios({
            method: 'post',
            
            data: formData,

            })
            

    }
    const {acceptedFiles, getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone();

    console.log(props.id)

    const files = acceptedFiles.map(file => (
        <li key={file.path}>
            {file.path}
            - {file.size}
            bytes
        </li>
    ));

   

    return (
        <section className="container">
            <div {...getRootProps({className: 'dropzone'})}>
                <input {...getInputProps()}/>
                <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
            </div>
            {files.length > 0 && <React.Fragment>
                <div>
                    <h4>Files</h4>
                    <ul>{files}</ul>
                </div>
                <button onClick={uploadFiles}>Submit</button>
            </React.Fragment>}

        </section>
    );
}

export class UploadManuscript extends Component {

    render() {
      

        return (<Basic/>)
    }
}

export default UploadManuscript
```

Comment: "I have done it"... dude you saved my fkin life